# gmock - setting expectations for same object with same parameters in differenct methods

Tags: c++, googlemock

Let's say that class TEST contains enough large logic so for every UT of it I need to set up many expectations for mock classes used in TEST class. Every UT will has his own expectations, but some of them are same. So having many UT for TEST class I would like to move some of expectations to other method so a UT code will be more readable:

```
class SetUpClass
{
    ClassAMock // let's assume that it's testing::NiceMock for some class A
    void SetSomeExpectations() //because most/all tests cases will need that expectation let's put it here 
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(ClassAMock, SomeMethod()).Times(1);
    }
}

(SomeTest, SetUpClass)
{
    // preparing expectations
    // below one is generic
    SetSomeExpectations();

    // but this test needs additional expectations for ClassAMock SomeMethod
    EXPECT_CALL(ClassAMock, SomeMethod()).Times(2);

    // Run tests
    ...
}
```

So what I would like to achieve is to be able to sum those expectations, so finally gmock expects SomeMethod to be called 3 times. Is it even possible? I couldn't find anything similar in the Internet. It seems that each calling Times overrides previous one, not sum them.

Comment: Have you looked/tried test fixtures? https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests-same-data-multiple-tests

Comment: @Bart Yes, SetUpClass is a test fixture class. It doesn't inherited from :testing::Test because I am using boost test framework for testing, but gmock for setting expectations and gmocks. And as I showed in example calling SetSomeExpectations from a test fixture class doesn't work, since expectations set in SomeTest overrided it.

Comment: Do they override or not care about the order? By default gmock does not care about the order mocks are called in. I often use `InSequence seq` but this is definitely a scoped class which only works within the same scope. A really ugly hack would be to use a macro :-(

Comment: Well they do override calls for expectations, so when I call in one file
        EXPECT_CALL(ClassAMock, SomeMethod()).Times(1);
        EXPECT_CALL(ClassAMock, SomeMethod()).Times(2);
gmock will expect SomeMethod to be called 2 times, not 3.

Comment: Do you need to know the mock happens? If not you can leave them out if you have no side effects like return values or expected parameters. I am using mocks where I have different parameter values and am able to stack those with no problem but they are all in the same scope. example: https://github.com/Embedded-AMS/EmbeddedProto/blob/master/test/test_RepeatedFieldMessage.cpp

Comment: I do want to have control over all mocks, so I need to handle all expectations. Without that I don't see much sense in using gmocks if I don't use expectations on mocks... I can see that Times() returns an object, but still I don't see any options to manipulate times parameter. I guess it's not support and that's all story. I can have some local variable that I will modify and at the end I will pass to Times() but it is quite ugly solution.